# How do I replace a ZX Spectrum 48k keyboard membrane?

Tags: zx-spectrum, keyboards, maintenance, membrane-keyboard

I have a ZX Spectrum 48k on which the keyboard membrane has cracked over the years and, while the Speccy itself is operational, has rendered the computer unusable. I am now in possession of a replacement membrane keyboard for the Spectrum, but I can find no guides as to how I should replace it.

What is the correct way to replace the membrane keyboard on a ZX Spectrum (48k)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the keyboard itself:

1. Undo the screws from the bottom of the case.
2. Lift the top of the case gently off.
3. Disconnect the ribbon cables from the keyboard (CAREFUL fragile)
4. Slide out the keyboard.
5. Insert the new one and attach the ribbon cables.
6. Clip the case back together and do up the screws

For the membrane:

1. Prise the top off the case - early models were clipped, later ones glued
2. Gently pull the keyboard membrane and its support out of the case.
3. Blow out the years of accumulated grot.
4. Slide the new keyboard and membrane back in.
5. Clip / tack the case back together.

There is a much longer guide [here](http://www.dataserve-retro.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d31.html) with pictures.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is pretty easy.

Dataserve is a great site, devoted to retro computing.

And if you want a video showing you how, to minimise getting it wrong, here is one from Mark Fixes Stuff on YouTube

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=O61Yy00GHEc

And if you are buying, SellMyRetro is a good site.

Make sure you buy the right membrane. For example, the Spectrum + membrane is different to the rubber key 48k and 16k.